# Reuse a Part of a git Repository

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I have the following project setup:

- `Solution A`

  - `Project 1` (a lightweight component)
  - `Project 2` (contains a lot of files and depends on `Project 1`)

`Solution A` is a single **git** repository. Then I created another solution and found that I could reuse and even update the functionality of `Project 1`. So my second solution would probably look like this:

- `Solution B`

  - *`Project 1`* (must be shared!)
  - `Project 3` (depends on `Project 1`).

Now I want `Project 1` to become a shared component. That is, every time I change the source code of `Project 1` from either solution (`A` or `B`), I need the other one to update accordingly.

Maybe this has something to do the the **submodule** feature of **git**. However, the only way I was able to use it is to specify the whole `Solution A` as a submodule for `Solution B`. This is not really what I want ideally due to enormous size of `Solution A`. I only need a tiny part of it to be a submodule.

I know that it's possible in **svn** and works exactly as I've described: you specify a directory within an external repository in the `svn:externals` property.

Any tips on that? Or maybe, I'm missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is definitely related to submodules (see the [nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194))

In your case, the ideal solution would be to extract `Project1` from `SolutionA` Git repo:
See [How to extract a git subdirectory and make a submodule out of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920165/howto-extract-a-git-subdirectory-and-make-a-submodule-out-of-it).

But that involves rewriting SolutionA history, which is a problem if you have already published it and if some people are pulling from it.

Using [filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) for the extraction process.

> To rewrite the repository to look as if `Project1/`  had been its project root, and discard all other history:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter Project1 -- --all
```

> Thus you can, e.g., turn a library subdirectory into a repository of its own. Note the `--` that separates `filter-branch` options from revision options, and the `--all` to rewrite all branches and tags.

Then declare `Project1` as a submodule in `SolutionB`:

```
cd SolutionB
git submodule add /path/to/Project1 Project1
```

> NOTE: Do not use local URLs here if you plan to publish your `SolutionB`!

```
git commit -m "Add submodules Project1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Split Project 1 out to its own repository, and make it a submodule of both Solution A and Solution B.