# How to use a common repository from Git in multiple Visual Studio solutions

Tags: git, visual-studio

A question about Git.  In my own work, I usually create a common library that sits in it's own project.  I import that project into various other solutions.

With Git, how would one have that common library in its own repository and be available to other projects (repositories) that are being used in Visual Studio?

The issue there is that those are separate repositories.

It it possible to work with a solution with multiple repo's?

Thank you.

Comment: either look into git submodules, or something like https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/ or http://linux.die.net/man/1/mr

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reuse a Part of a git Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326299/reuse-a-part-of-a-git-repository)