# Checking out only a subdirectory of another repo with git-submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I need to only add a part (a directory) of another project within my "superproject", so I'd like to know if it is possible with git-submodule to only add a certain directory from another repository to my project?

(I'm using git for the deployment as well, so I do not want to stuff my project with other unnecessary things.)

Comment: [Howto extract a git subdirectory and make a submodule out of it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920165/howto-extract-a-git-subdirectory-and-make-a-submodule-out-of-it); [Detach subdirectory into separate Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

Answer (score 1):

You could make a bare repo and then just use `git checkout` with the `--work-tree` and `--git-dir` parameter after the git command and specify the branch/tag you want and then specify the path you want after the `--` file specifier option. Example:

```
git --git-dir=somedir --work-tree=someotherdir checkout somebranchortag -- somepath
```

Hope this helps.