# Import part of a SVN repository into an existing Git repo

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn, svn2git

I have an existing SVN repo and I would like to import a part of it, with history into an existing Git repo. Could anyone give me a high-level overview of the commands needed to do this?

Summary:

- I want to move some subdirectories in an existing SVN repository (but not the rest of the repo)
- I have an existing Git repo that I want to import those directories into
- I want to preserve the history of just the subdirectories I moved (but not anything else)

I have a feeling this involves something with `git filter-branch` and some strange merges. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect it might be easier to import the full repository, then use `git filter-branch` to prune out the stuff you don't want to keep. I'm not sure it's even possible to only import part of an `svn` repository in that way, and even if you can it's not likely to be simple...

Comment: You can dump the Subversion repository using `svnadmin dump`, and then use [`svndumpfilter`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.html) to filter out the parts you don't want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out to be pretty complicated, but here's what I did.

1. Prepare the SVN repository first. I was going to delete the files from SVN afterward, so it helped to put all the files in one directory (this also makes `filter-branch` easier later.)
2. Checked out the SVN repo using git: `git svn clone http://path/to/svnrepo`. This creates a git version of the svn repo.
3. Using the ideas from this SO post, [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository), I used the `filter-branch --subdirectory-filter` to filter the directory that I wanted, and to remove history of other stuff from SVN that I did not want to keep in git. You can also use `git subtree`, a new feature, as in [Howto extract a git subdirectory and make a submodule out of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920165/howto-extract-a-git-subdirectory-and-make-a-submodule-out-of-it/1307969#1307969)
4. Then, using the ideas from this SO post, [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories), I imported the new git repo into the parent project that I wanted to add it to. The accepted answer is incorrect, check out the other answers on that page; you want to do a `git remote add git-proj <path>` followed by a `git pull`.
5. Finally, push the changes to the git project.

Comment: worked for me but with git merge --allow-unrelated-histories origin/master to merge the repositories (found from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)