# How to create branch/worktree from local repo containing local submodule commits

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

The flow is simple:

- I have cloned a repo named `project`. I have also cloned another repo `addon`, embedding it as a submodule within `project`.

```
- project
--- addon
------ z.c
--- x.c
--- y.c
```

- I've made changes to some files inside `addon`. I've committed these changes to both `addon` and the super-project `project`. But I have **not** pushed them anywhere -- these changes are entirely local.
- Now, I'd like to create a separate branch/worktree of `project` at another location, named `otherProject`. This new worktree should contain all the parent's files as they are currently, **including** the `addon` submodule at its current state, preserving its history.

```
git worktree add -b otherProject path/to/otherProject HEAD
```

### How do I do this?

Currently, the above command doesn't transfer the submodule. Instead, the new worktree's `addon` folder is empty.

---

Some of what I've tried:

- `git submodule update --recursive` does NOT work. When I run it in the new worktree, it tries to fetch the current submodule commit from the original server `origin`, which of course fails because the server doesn't have my local `addon` commits. The errors are along the lines of:

```
error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object 987e772b2...
fatal: Fetched in submodule path `addon`, but it did not contain  987e772b2...
```

- `git checkout --recurse-submodules` does NOT seem to work. It doesn't return any error but when I run `git status -uno` afterwards, I get this:

```
Submodules changed but not updated:

Warn: addon doesn't contain commit 987e772b2...
```

- I tried changing the new worktree's URL in `.gitmodules` to the local path of the parent repo, but that doesn't help -- it still tries to pull from the remote server. ([Some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60953912/creating-a-local-git-submodule) seem to imply that one can create submodules from absolute local paths as URL, though this isn't mentioned AT ALL in the docs.)
- Running `git checkout` inside the new worktree's `addon` folder populates it with files -- but these are files taken from the remote server. They do not contain my local changes.

Comment: One thing that DOES work now is -- editing the parent repo's `.git/worktrees/<worktreeName>/modules/<submoduleName>/config`, replace the `remote "origin"` URL with the absolute *local* path of the parent `project/addon` submodule. But this is clearly a garbage solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my last comment on remote-origins led me to check out the `submodule update` command in more detail. It seems it accepts a `--reference` option which it passes to any potential `clone` calls internally. And this option can apparently accept a local path, per the [Git-URLs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#URLS) page.

So, basically, I can run this command inside the new worktree `otherProject`:

```
git submodule update --recursive --reference <Absolute-Local-Path-To-Parent-Submodule>

e.g.

git submodule update --recursive --reference C:/project/addon
```

... and the `addon` submodule gets cloned from there directly, pointing at the submodule-commit bound to the worktree's HEAD.

So far, things look fine. The now-cloned submodule has a detached HEAD, which is easily fixed with `git checkout -b newAddonBranchName`.

I don't know if this is the "correct" way to do this -- if anyone has a better suggestion, they're most welcome to post it.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a "correct" way to handle this: it's not really an anticipated workflow in the submodule world. (Submodules predate `git worktree` and `git worktree` itself doesn't pay any attention to submodules. The problem might be in this last part, the lack-of-attention here, but I think for the most part the problems with submodules are because submodules themselves are deeply flawed...)

Comment: Understood -- and heartily agree with the last part, based off my limited forays at least. I'll take this solution for now, hoping nothing's broken.