# How to git if I am already gitting? (git manage a subfolder of an already git managed folder)

Tags: git

This is a question that has been calling my attention.

Say I have a folder `base_folder` and in this folder I have some files. I do `git init` on this, put a `.gitignore` file, and commit, no problem.

Later, for no particular reason I make a directory inside: `project_folder`

In this folder I put several files that are of a different nature. I build my code, everything is going great.

Then I realize that I would like to git manage the project in `project_folder` separately, perhaps even put it in github.

But this folder is being managed already for the repo in `base_folder`.

How do I git manage my repo in `project_folder`?

What I tried

I put a `.gitignore` folder inside `project_folder` but is being completely ignored by git. Why is that and how git ignore in subdrectories work?

Comment: Are you expect to have whole separate repos or first repo still have to be connected with second one?

Comment: I am open to both, but the original idea was to have separate repos

Comment: @RomainValeri Added some clarification

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract a git subdirectory and make a submodule out of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920165/how-to-extract-a-git-subdirectory-and-make-a-submodule-out-of-it)

Answer (score 0):

You need to un-do some pictures you have in your head.  They're leading you in the wrong direction.

Git doesn't manage folders or files.  Git manages (and stores, and uses, and transfers, etc) *commits*.  Git is thus all about commits.

Each commit does have files, but Git doesn't really treat them as "folders": files just have names, which may well contain embedded (forward) slashes.  This is the case even on Windows, where the OS uses backslashes.  That is, "foo/bar" is not a file named "bar" in a folder named "foo", in Git; it's just a file named "foo/bar".

Your OS, of course, requires that these committed files be *extracted to* a folder named "foo".  Git will therefore first create `foo` if necessary, so as to create `foo\bar` or whatever your OS insists on calling this thing.  But to Git, that's just a file named `foo/bar`.  That is, the *working tree* files are organized into folders.  But the stored-in-Git, compressed, de-duplicated, read-only, Git-ized files in the *commits* are—via Git's *index* / *staging-area*—just names with slashes in them.

What this means is that if you have commits that contain files named `project_folder/file1`, `project_folder/file2`, and so on, your Git will create `project_folder` and inside that, create `file1` and `file2` and so on.  If you have commits that *don't* have any files whose name starts with `project_folder/`, Git *won't* create a folder of that name (but won't necessarily *delete* one, if you create one yourself).

When you *check out* some commit (with `git checkout` or the newfangled `git switch`), Git will *remove* all the working tree files it created earlier from the *current commit* (that you're switching away from), and *extract* all the files in the *target commit* (that you're switching to).  Once done, the target commit *is* the current commit, so that these files will be removed and replaced with other files if you switch yet again.

What `.gitignore` is about has to do with creating new commits—but it's rather indirect.  When Git *creates* a new commit, it packages up *all the files that are in Git's index / staging area right at that time*.  These are the same files Git extracted, in the extraction step.  Git extracts them to *both* Git's index *and* your working tree, so now those files exist in both places.  There are, in effect, *three* copies of each file, at all times:

- There's one in the `HEAD` (current) commit, that Git initially extracted.
- There's one in Git's index right now.  If you haven't changed this copy, it's the one Git extracted initially.
- Last, there's one in your working tree.  If you haven't changed this copy, it's *also* the one Git extracted—but it's not in Git's special, read-only, compressed and de-duplicated form.

When you modify some working tree files, you presumably would like the updated copies to go into your *next* commit.  So you run:

```
git add file1 file3
```

for instance.  This tells Git: *make the index copy match the working-tree copy.*  You changed the working tree copy of `file1`, so Git compresses, Git-ifies, and de-duplicates the new `file1` contents.  If they're a duplicate, Git finds what they're a duplicate *of* (in any earlier commit, anywhere) and they're now de-duplicated and ready to go.  If they're all-new contents, Git prepares the all-new, compressed, ready-to-go contents.

Git now repeats this for `file3`, since your `git add` listed both files.  If there's *no* index copy of `file3` yet, because it's all-new, Git compresses the contents, checks to see if this duplicates any previous file ever committed, and prepares the index copy either way, just as it did for `file1`.  Now there's an index copy of `file3`, ready to go in the new commit.

When you run `git commit`, Git simply packages up *everything that is in the index right now*.  So Git's index, which we also call the staging area, is your *proposed next commit*.  What you do with `git add` is update your *proposed next commit*, using the regular (non-Git) files you are manipulating in your working tree.

If you accidentally copy, into Git's index / staging area, some file such as `config/local.config` that you didn't mean to propose including in a future commit, you will need to remove this Git-ified file from Git's index / staging area.  You can do this with `git rm --cached config/local.config`, for instance.

The `.gitignore` file is about *keeping certain working tree files out of the staging area*.  It *only affects files that aren't in the staging area right now*.  It tells Git: *When I use some `git add` command that would otherwise add this file as a new file, **don't add it**.*  This lets you use `git add .` or `git add *` without having to worry about these particular files.

In the end, then, these are your building blocks:

- Git stores *commits*.
- Each commit gets a unique (across all Git clones everywhere) hash ID.
- You make *new* commits by adjusting what's in Git's index, aka the staging area.  While `git status` shows you what's in the staging area, it does so by *comparing* the staging area (twice: once to the current commit, then a second time, to your working tree).  It doesn't bother mentioning the things that *match:* it only tells you what's *different*.
- You adjust what's in Git's index using `git add`, or—to remove something entirely—`git rm`.
- You work on (regular, ordinary, non-Git) files, using non-Git editors and all other commands your computer has, in your working tree.
- Some files that are in your working tree aren't necessarily *in* Git at all, or at least, aren't in the *current commit*, and hence maybe are not in Git's index yet either.
- A file that *is* in your working tree, but is *not* in Git's index, is an *untracked file*.  It doesn't matter how the file got this way, just that it *is* this way.
- The `.gitignore` file just tells `git add` that particular *untracked* files should *stay* untracked, and that when `git status` is about to tell you about some untracked file, it should shut its yap if that file is listed in `.gitignore`.  This lets you keep these files untracked, and not see complaints about them.  It won't help you with a tracked file: you need to use `git rm --cached` to make that file become *untracked* before `.gitignore` will take hold.  (Note that `git rm` without `--cached` removes both the index copy *and* the working tree copy.)

All of this is with respect to *one* Git repository.  A Git *submodule* is the way you get one Git repository to **refer to** another Git repository.  Git refuses to let one Git repository *contain* another Git repository, but you're allowed to have entries (in Git's index and in commits) that say *use commit _____ (fill in the blank with a hash ID) from some other Git repository*.  For this to work, the other Git repository must exist and must contain that commit.